# xcodebuild: Provisioning profile doesn't include device

Tags: flutter, xcodebuild, provisioning, xcode10.3

### Problem:

- Run with `Xcode10.3` or `vscode with flutter` are fine.
- Run with `xcodebuild command` failed:
  `Provisioning profile` doesn't include the currently `selected device` "[MyPhone]". (in target 'Runner')

#### On Device

Use Xcode `run on device are fine`.Use `xcodebuild` command in terminal failed:

> xcodebuild -configuration Debug -target Runner  -arch armv6 -sdk iphoneos

```
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = armv6
    SDKROOT = iphoneos12.4


2019-08-10 08:52:54.739 xcodebuild[23765:932559]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 
1daca728d755****0[MyPhoneUUID] was NULL
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
Build system information
error: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.xxxx.xxxx" 
doesn't include the currently selected device "[MyPhone]". (in target 'Runner')

Build system information
warning: None of the architectures in ARCHS (armv6) are valid for this target. 
Consider setting ARCHS to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) or updating it to include at least
one value from VALID_ARCHS (arm64, arm64e, armv7, armv7s). (in target 'Runner')

Build system information
warning: ignoring duplicated output file: '[Project_Path]/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/
Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework' in shell script build phase '[CP] Embed 
Pods Frameworks'. This warning represents an extremely serious project misconfiguration 
and will likely cause some shell scripts in your project to be skipped entirely, 
leading to other build failures or missing files in the build directory. This will
be a hard error in the future. (in target 'Runner')
```

Is there a way to find out what kind of command Xcode run when debug on device.

#### On Simulator

Use Xcode `run on simulator iPhone 7(iOS12.4) are fine`.
But use `xcodebuild` command in terminal failed:

> xcodebuild -configuration Debug -target Runner  -sdk iphonesimulator

```
Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator12.4

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Using build description from disk
Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '[Project_Path]/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/
Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework':
1) Target 'Runner' has copy command from 
 '[Project_Path]/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework' to 
 '[Project_Path]/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script
 phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”

Build system information
warning: ignoring duplicated output file: '[Project_Path]/build/ios/
Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework' in shell script build 
phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'. This warning represents an extremely serious 
project misconfiguration and will likely cause some shell scripts in your project to 
be skipped entirely, leading to other build failures or missing files in the build 
directory. This will be a hard error in the future. (in target 'Runner')
```

### Update

`-arch armv6` should be `-arch armV7` when on device.

> xcodebuild -configuration Debug -target Runner  -arch armv7 -sdk iphoneos

#### after clean or maybe mistake delete more files

Run with Xcode works.
Run with above command:

```
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = armv7
    SDKROOT = iphoneos12.4

2019-08-10 13:09:30.105 xcodebuild[3131:1467212]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 
1daca728d755****0[MyPhoneUUID] was NULL
2019-08-10 13:09:30.147 xcodebuild[3131:1467213]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 
1daca728d755****0[MyPhoneUUID] was NULL
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
Build system information
error: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.xxxx.xxx" doesn't 
include the currently selected device "[MyPhoneName]". (in target 'Runner')
```

### Update 2

This problem is caused by iPhone is `locked` when using `xcodebuild`.
Make sure device is `plugging` and `unlocked` and run with `xcodebuild` are works.

> <s>DTDeviceKit: deviceType from  [PhoneUUID] was NULL.</s>

### Update 3

With cleaning all:

- delete all `iPhone Developer certificate` in keychain.
- delete all `iPhone Developer certificate` in apple account.
- delete all profiles in folder `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`.
- using Xcode/ref/myAccount/"Download Manual Profiles" to download all profile and after this there's a new auto generated certificate with name "YourNameOnMac(YourMacName)".

Result:

- Run with Xcode works.
- Run the project through CI (codemagic confic with `manual sign config: .p12 + profile`) works.
- Run with command still failed(I update `armv7` to `arm64`)

> xcodebuild -configuration Debug -target Runner  -arch arm64 -sdk iphoneos

```
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = arm64
    SDKROOT = iphoneos12.4

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Using build description from disk
Build system information
error: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.xxxx.xxx" doesn't 
include the currently selected device "[MyPhoneName]". (in target 'Runner')

Build system information
warning: ignoring duplicated output file: '[Project_Path]/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/
Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework' in shell script build phase '[CP] Embed 
Pods Frameworks'. This warning represents an extremely serious project misconfiguration 
and will likely cause some shell scripts in your project to be skipped entirely, 
leading to other build failures or missing files in the build directory. This will
be a hard error in the future. (in target 'Runner')
```

#### Update 4.

- Uncheck `Automatic manage signing` to see if it related to `Team` only profile problem, still failed.
- But run `flutter` with `vscode` & run it in `Xcode` both works.

Answer (score 0):

Given this question's age, I'm curious if this issue is still relevant. While I'm unable to replicate this behavior, I suggest trying the [solution on this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65192513/2497859) and see if it works for your setup.